# Output product collection into a table along with static element in Shopify

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, shopify, liquid

I need to output a collection of products into a table on my index page. What is the best way to do this? I was looking in the docs and found the tablerow stuff. The problem is, that products are going to need to come out two at a time, that is there are two images in every row (two different products) and then in the next row are the names. I did things this way because it was the easiest way to keep everything lined up properly as the image sizes tend to change. Also, there's a static element that needs to be output into the table too. Any advice on this?

Here's the store:

https://hodkiewicz-zieme-and-hirthe180.myshopify.com/

Here's the relevant code:

```
  <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="{{'carb-1.png' | asset_url}}"></td>
          <td><img src="{{'carb-2.png' | asset_url}}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1930 Speedster</td>
          <td>1929-1931 Super 8</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="{{'carb-3.png' | asset_url}}"></td>
        <td><img src="{{'carb-4.png' | asset_url}}"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1932 Super 8</td>
        <td>1929-1931 Standard 8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="{{'box.png' | asset_url}}"></td>
        <td><img src="{{'carb-5.png' | asset_url}}"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1932 Standard 8</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

At the moment, I'm statically outputting all of the relevant images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each image and the associated description in a div and output them together in a single table cell. That way you can still output everything using the `tablerow` instruction.

Furthermore, you can get clever with your static content and render that in the `tablerow` loop too. Use a combination of the [row and column identifiers listed on the Shopify Wiki](http://wiki.shopify.com/Liquid#Tables) to find the cell you want the static content in, and render that instead of a product when you hit the correct cell.

Your code might look something like this

```
  {% tablerow item in items cols: 3 %}
    {% if tablerowloop.col_first &&  tablerowloop.last %}
      <!-- Display static content! -->
    {% else %}
      <div class='table-item'>
        {{item.image}}
        <p>{{item.title}}</p>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endtablerow %}
```

Comment: Where do we add this code?